# Lotus Notes: Corrupted ID file

Tags: email, lotus

I'm working as service desk guy. An user has reported today, that he's unable to start his Lotus Notes client because of getting this error: *Problem with ID*. I have asked our Lotus Notes/Domino administrators if they have any idea what might be wrong, but they just simply turned me down saying the user should ask his local IT team for help, which is hardly a solution, because the user is somewhere in Asia on weak (if any) internet connection most of the time.

I'm quite positive something must be wrong with his local ID file, because he is able to send e-mails from Lotus Traveler and probably webmail too (but hasn't confirmed that yet).

I would be grateful for any suggestions what might be causing the error and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Id file is corrupt then the only solution is to replace the id file with a working copy. There is no "id- fixup" or any other cure for a defective id.

In an environment, where all possibilities that IBM delivers are in use, getting a new id file is as easy as deleting the old one and restarting the client.

This function is called "Id Vault".

Without a vault, someone at the helpdesk has to either
- recover the ide using the id recovery (if in use, it is the function that was used before id vault)
- get the id file from a backup
- recreate the id file (loosing all encrypted data that has been encrypted with the broken id)

So: there is nothing for you to do, as all of these steps need a domino- administrator.

As written earlier: the only chance is to rename the id... If ID Vault is in place, it will be automatically recreated